# Unity: Machine learning - level solving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, machine-learning

Recently I've been messing around with machine learning and I wanted to see if I could create AI for the game I'm currently making. The AI should be able to solve the puzzle for you.

The game currently works as followed. You have a few tiles in a grid, some of them are movable some of them aren't. You click on a tile you want to move, and you drag it into a direction. It'll then start moving the tiles and optionally also the player character itself. The end goal is to reach the end tile.  [Level example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT9wc.png), [Solving the level](https://gfycat.com/AmusedOptimisticJanenschia)

Playing the game yourself:
Whenever you select a tile (you do this by clicking), you then hold the mouse button down, and drag onto the direction you want the tile to move towards. Once the tiles are done moving, the player object will move one step in the same direction. If the player is on top of a tile that you move, it'll move with the tile. And afterwards do another step in the same direction.

I was wondering if it's possible (and if so, how) for machine learning to define a position on the screen, (optionally) click and then define a movement direction?

Please keep in mind that I'm fairly new to machine learning!

To give some more clarification:

- The grid is static for now, to keep it simple for the AI. But later one, the goal is to generate a level randomly, and see if it can solve it.
- In theory, all the AI should have to do, is select a tile to move (A number between 0 and the width of the grid, and the same for the height). And define a movement direction. Either (0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0) or (-1, 0).
- Falling off the grid will results in a reset.
- Reaching the end of the grid results in a win.
- Moving in an invalid direction results in a reset.

Comment: Machine learning for such task is either done through image processing (so you would have to capture the screen), or through 'access' to the game state (which is preferrable) with this i mean, it can read the objects in the grid (or however you designed it). When the ai knows what to do, do you want to mimic the mouse movements, or do you want to 'do the interactions' without moving the mouse?

Comment: Technically anything is possible. Your question is a little unclear. Do you want to know how to get input from the mouse? Do you want to know code for machine learning? I would instead forget about the mouse, and just measure the movements on the board made by the person. You can then create a valuation system for the machine. You haven't specified if the problem will change everytime, what variables are involved, etc.

Comment: @h-j-meijer I was personally thinking, that if it can simply select a tile of the grid (by selecting a value between 0 and max width (same for height). Which will then retrieve a tile of the grid. And then state a direction it should move in. Either (0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0) or (-1, 0). This is already sufficient for a movement input, and the rest of the game will handle the remaining logic.

Comment: so, 1) you do not want to "read the screen", doing it via gamestate would be sufficient? and 2) you want to mimic mouse input to do the actual actions?

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper I'll quickly update the post!

Comment: @H.J.Meijer 1) Yes, it would be sufficient to do it through the game state. 2) If the AI is able to generate a movement direction based on the direction of the end goal, that would in theory already be sufficient.

Comment: So basically the AI should navigate between obstacles to reach the end tile?

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper Yes, that's correct. I just added another gif to showcase how this level would be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off of your bullet points, I would honestly suggest just implementing the [A* Pathfinding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), with some modifications to *emulate* machine learning. The A* Pathfinding algorithm determines the best path on a grid from point `a` to point `b`, and using clever programming you could achieve the result you want with a reasonable amount of overhead.

Something along the lines of having a list of "do not touch" grid points(death traps, etc), which gets filled *as* the AI runs into them, so on the next iteration it knows not to take that path. This is a very basic abstraction of your idea, but would be highly obtainable.

Obviously we cannot write the code for you, luckily there are tons of resources on A* Pathfinding to help you get started!

- [Here is a simple tutorial](https://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/a-pathfinding-example-in-c/)
- [Here is an implementation that was used in Unity](https://gist.github.com/keithcollins/307c3335308fea62db2731265ab44c06)
- [Here is a code review on someones implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114512/simple-pathfinding-algorithm)

Comment: Thanks for the commendation. It is 100% faster/better to write an algorithm to solve this for me. But it’s just an experiment to see if I can make use of machine learning. Anyway, I’ll be sure to look into this!

Comment: @FeikoJoosten If you're indeed just trying to experiment with ML, you should mark Tyler S. Loeper's answer as the accepted answer; his is much more relevant to the context. I was under the assumption that since you're using Unity, that you knew what you wanted but you weren't sure exactly how to get there, so I gave you the most efficient approach. Tyler's answer will help you, and anyone else who stumbles here more appropriately. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Yeah, was thinking about that as well. Anyway, thanks for your answer anyway!

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming you actually want to use machine learning and not just a pathing system:**

I will lay out some pseudo code that you can use for a basic scenario of the AI learning a static board. There are different ways you can write and implement this code, I have only suggested one way. But before we get to that lets first discuss this project overall and some suggestions for it.

**Suggestions:**

1. I would say that you will want to measure the game state on the board, and not the mouse movements. So basically the AI is measuring what moves can be made. The mouse movement part is just a way for the player to interact with the board so it is not needed by the AI. It will be simpler to just let the AI make the moves directly.
2. I don't think that unity is a good platform for this kind of experimentation. I think you would be better off programming this in a console program. So for example using a 2 dimensional array (board) in a visual studio c# console program, or in a C console program via CS50 IDE (comes with free sign up via edx.org for cs50 https://manual.cs50.net/ide). I have suggested these because I think Unity will just add unnecessary layers to a machine learning experiment.

My assumption is you want to learn machine learning, and not just how to make an ai solve a puzzle in your game. Because in the latter case better options would be a proper pathing system, or having the ai brute force several attempts at the puzzle before moving and select the solution with the fewest steps.

**Pseudo Code:**

Now onto some pseudo code for your machine learning program.

---

*Assumptions:*

A. You have a board with set dimensions that you can pass to the Ai at the start.

B. There are tiles on the board the AI cannot move into (obstacles).

C. The AI should learn to solve the problem, instead of having the answer at the beginning because of good code that we designed (like a decent pathing system).

D. We don't want the AI to brute force this by trying a billion different combinations before moving, because this suggests perfect understanding of its environment. If the ai has perfect understanding of its environment then yes, it should use brute force where reasonable.

---

*Coding Logic:
Scenario 1: The AI plays on the same board every time with the same starting conditions.*

I. You start by setting a discrete amount of time in which the AI makes a move. For example 1 move every 1 second.

II. Have a counter for the number of moves made to reach the end tile, and record the sequence of moves associated with this counter.

III. If the AI has no history with which to make a move it makes a move in a random direction.

IV. If the move is invalid then the counter increases and the move is recorded, but the AI stays on the same tile.

V. When the AI completes the puzzle the counter and sequence of moves is stored for later use.

VI. In subsequent play throughs the AI always starts by selecting the paths it has tried with smallest count.

VII. Once the AI begins moving it has a 1% chance per move to try something different. Here is an example. When the 1% is triggered the AI has a 50% to try one of the following:

**a**. 50% chance: It checks through all the sequences in its history to see if there is any section in the past sequences where the counter between its current tile and the finish tile is shorter than its current path. If there are multiple it selects the shortest. When the AI finishes the round it records the new total sequence taken.

**b**. 50% chance. The Ai makes a move in a random direction. If it made a move in a random direction. Subsequent moves again follow this logic of 50% chance check, and 50% chance move randomly again. When completed again record the sequence of moves.

VIII. You can seed this by making the AI run the puzzle a 10,000 times in a few seconds behind the scenes, and then when you observe it afterwards it should have selected a reasonable path.

---

If a computer can brute force a problem in reasonable time it should start with that. However bear in mind that machine learning in a computer program where the machine already knows all the variables is different from machine learning in the environment, where for example you have a robot that has to navigate an unknown environment. The above code should work in the latter case. You may also want to investigate the idea of the AI mapping out the entire terrain by trying to move to every tile and forming an understanding of the environment, then just brute forcing a solution once it understands the variables.

In a non static environment you will want to enhance the valuation system. This answer is already too long so I won't go into it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to both questions: Yes,

You can create an ai that uses either gamestate (so it can read the objects/properties of your grid) or you could use raw-screen input combined with image processing, which is a hard thing to create, and expensive (computational) to run.

On the Unity forms there are several answers to the question "How to mimic mouse input" or alike. Take a look here:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/564664/how-i-can-move-mouse-cursor-without-mouse-but-with.html

If you are looking for the code for the AI, sadly, you are out of luck. There are lots of ai tutorials online to create a simple ai for such a game. I would advice not to dive head-first in the fancy stuff (like neural networks) and start simple. It would be the best, in my opinion, too start with creating an (class) structure for your ai, and start learning AI by practice. Start with an "AI" that just randomly returns something, then see what you can learn & manage online and make other versions.

For one of the first AI's, take a look into goal-driven AI's or state-machines. I think they should be able to give nice results, given your gifs.